# Categorisation of potential research?

Tags: discussion, tags

Every now and then, questions are bound (hopefully at least) to uncover things that could/should be researched. I was thinking about a potential tag (such as [future-research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-research) or [currently-unknown](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-unknown)?) to categorise such questions, labelling them as currently unanswerable and maybe they will be valuable as input if visitors are looking for areas of knowledge to be uncovered. I just had the idea and was wondering if people would think it of any use :) I'm sure it wouldn't be very useful at the moment, but maybe in the future?

Comment: There is a moderator notice that we can put on if it's warranted, see example on this question.  EDIT: However the wording of it has apparently changed dramatically since I last looked at it and it doesn't seem appropriate anymore <_<

Comment: Well... if once or twice in a decade counts as rapidly changing, that applies to a lot of questions here... xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a meta-tag, and they are generally problematic, [see this blog post for more information about meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Aside from that I think the decision whether something is worth investigating or not is very subjective. And the list of everything we don't know is probably too long to be useful.

This shouldn't stop you from compiling a list of interesting topics out of questions here, just tags aren't the right way to go about this.

Comment: Very nice blog post which immediately reminded me of [tag:homework] :) A tag was the best way I could think of; though the idea was something like half-closing the question and marking it as resolved even if, strictly, it's not (i.e. resolved by current knowledge).